# Чтение переписки через JavaMail API

Tags: java, javamail

Всем привет!)
Хотел бы узнать можно ли через JavaMail API каким то образом сделать выборку сообщений в почте например с каким то пользователем, например с example@example.ex и получить всю переписку на сервер? То есть, ожидаю получить все сообщения которые я отправлял ему и все сообщения которые он отправлял мне.
Каких то конкретных примеров кроме отправки сообщение через это API не нашёл. Существует ли такая возможность, если да, то что нужно использовать или может есть какой то туториал?

Comment: https://javaee.github.io/javamail/#Samples + https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaMail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подключаешься по протоколу IMAP, сначала читаешь папку входящие, потом исходящих. Делаешь цикл с проверкой отправителя. Вот так можно получить значения поля отправитель:

```
 Address[] froms = messages[i].getFrom();
                    String sender_var = froms == null ? null : ((InternetAddress) froms[0]).getAddress().toString();
```

И вытаскиваешь текст нужного сообщения:

```
String content = messages[i].getContent().toString();
```

Вот так читаешь саму папку:

```
inbox.open(Folder.READ или WRITE);
Message[] messages = inbox.getMessages();
```